# Error accessing to session variable from asp.net mvc view with IIS 7.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, session-variables

I have a ASP.NET MVC website.

I use HttpContext.Current.Session to store values.

From a view, I need a to access to a value using :

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Session["Value"];
```

It's working fine in most cases. (using IIS 8.5)

But when I host the application on another server with IIS 7.0, I get the error :

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Any idea what could be the problem ?

EDIT :

editing the applicationhost.config file with this fixed the problem :

```
<remove name="Session" /> 
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
```

But I get another problem with [Authorize] attribute...

> Unauthorized
>   You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referencing the variable itself or wanting the value of it?  Have you tried

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Session["Value"].Value
```

or

```
var value = HttpContext.Current.Session["Value"]
value.Value
```